# Must vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have their "tail" at origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I was looking the definition for an $n$-sphere centered at origin with radius $r$: $$\mathbb{S}^n = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : ||v|| = r \}$$

Although I understand that the $||v|| = r$ condition refers to all vectors $v$ with their initial point at origin for this definition to make sense.

But I always thought that $||v|| = r$ means the vector $v$ has length $r$. Any vector, even those far away from the original, can have lenght $r$, right? E.g. when $n = 2$, the vector $u = (0,10) - (0,9)$ is such that $||u|| = 1$, but it is not part of the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ centered at origin.

**Question**: what is the reason for my confusion? Is it because vectors in euclidean $n$-dimensional vector spaces should always have initial point at the origin? (**edit**: just realized this is rubbish since we can have vectors of the same length which are orthogonal)

Comment: When you think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ geometrically as a vector space, you are considering each vector as a direction arrow with a tail at the origin. So $(0, 10) - (0, 9)$ is an arrow $(0, 1)$ with a tail at the origin. Vectors here are only directions; the arrow you would want to draw from the head of one vector to the head of the other is not actually a vector unless you translate it back to the origin.

If you try to define a vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the geometric interpretation of addition above, you'll run into problems (e.g. with additive identity).

Comment: From Hubbard and Hubbard: "An element of $\mathbb R^n$ is simply an ordered list of $n$ numbers, but such a list can be interpreted in two ways: as a *point* representing a position or as a *vector* representing a displacement or increment."  In this definition of $\mathbb S^n$, I'd say we're thinking of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as a set of *points*, and $\mathbb S^n$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ whose distance from the origin is $r$.

Comment: @littleO - but isn't the norm only defined for vectors, not points?

Comment: Well, if $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $x$ is simply an ordered list of $n$ real numbers (regardless of how we visualize or think about $x$).  And $\|x\|$ is (by definition) equal to $\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$.  If we are thinking of $x$ as a vector, then we might interpret $\|x\|$ to be the length of $x$.  If we are thinking of $x$ as a point, then we might interpret $\|x\|$ to be the distance of $x$ from the origin.  This definition is simply saying that $\mathbb S^n$ is the set of all points whose distance from the origin is $r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one sense, yes; the tails of all vectors in a vector space are at the same point.

There is a related notion of an *affine space*, which is more or less the same thing as a vector space, but vectors can have tails at any point. We get a vector space by picking a point (it can be any point) and call it the "origin" -- then, the set of all vectors whose tail is at the origin becomes a vector space.

In another sense, no; we can think of vectors as being "unpinned" (not a technical term). A vector represents an abstract displacement that is not tied down to any particular point -- however, if we pick a particular point and call it the "origin", then we can produce a visual *representation* of the vector by drawing it as if it had a tail at the origin. And in this visualization, the zero vector always winds up simply pointing from the origin to itself.

(caution: the phrase "affine space" is often used to mean several different things)

Comment: Thanks! So, out of all vectors with their tails at the origin, the unit $n$-sphere centered at point $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ contains vectors $v$ such that $||v - c|| = 1$, treating the point $c$ as a vector with its tail at origin, right? I see. The definition of orthogonal complement to a element in the unit $1$-sphere centered at origin would be a line passing through origin, makes a lot more sense now. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors, on their own, can be thought as starting anywhere in space.

But usually we want to do more than that. We want to algebraic operations with them: we want to think of $\mathbb R^n$ as a vector space, even a normed space, or even an inner product space. These notions are defined naturally when we think of $\mathbb R^n$ as the set of vectors with start at the origin and end at a fixed point.